# Groovy collect over a String

Tags: groovy, collect

When I collect over a String I was expecting that `it` would be of type `char`, but it is `java.lang.String`. So why is this and how can I collect all characters of a String?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this...

```
someString.collect { 
    def c = it as char
    // carry on...
}
```

Or...

```
someString.chars.collect {
    // it will be a char
    // carry on...
}
```

Comment: Which one there an exception, and with which version of Groovy?

Comment: No now it worked ... I was trying to cast it to an int directly (`as int`), that was my mistake...

Answer (score 2):

In Groovy, a single character is also a String. In order to get each String as a Character use as:

```
"testString".collect { it as char }
```